# Integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\cos^2 x}{e^x-1}dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, riemann-zeta

I have encountered this integral and I am stuck evaluating it:$I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\cos^2 x}{e^x-1}dx$

My try was to expand the numerator into power series, indeed: $$x\cos^2x=\frac{x}{2}(1+\cos(2x)) =\frac{x}{2} +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n 2^{2n-1} x^{2n+1}}{(2n)!}$$ And using  $\zeta{(z)} \Gamma{(z)} =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{z-1}}{e^x-1}dx$ gives: $$I=\frac{1}{2}\zeta{(2)}+ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n 2^{2n-1}}{(2n)!} \zeta{(2n+2)} \Gamma{(2n+2)}=\frac{1}{2}\zeta{(2)}+ 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \zeta{(2n+2)}$$ Is there a way to simplify this? Or maybe another approach to this integral?

Edit: According to the answer in the comment, would this show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \zeta{(2n)}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}(2-3\text{ csch}^2(2\pi))+\frac{1}{16} $  ?

Comment: $\frac{1}{16}+\frac{\pi ^2}{12}-\frac{1}{4} \pi ^2 \text{csch}^2(2 \pi )$

Comment: See `mickep` answer.

Comment: $$\begin{align}S&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \zeta{(2n)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\zeta(4n-2)-\zeta(4n)\right]\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{\color{red}{m=1}}^{\infty}\left[\frac1{m^{4n-2}}-\frac1{m^{4n}}\right]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{\color{red}{m=2}}^{\infty}\left[\frac1{m^{4n-2}}-\frac1{m^{4n}}\right]\\&=\sum_{\color{red}{m=2}}^{\infty}\sum_{\color{blue}{n=1}}^{\infty}\left[\frac1{m^{4n-2}}-\frac1{m^{4n}}\right]=-\color{red}{\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}}\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}\left(-m^2\right)^{-n}\\&=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac1{m^2+1}=\frac{\pi}{2}\coth(\pi)-1\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x\cos^{2}\pars{x} \over \expo{x} - 1}\,\dd x}} =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over \expo{x} - 1}\,\dd x +
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x\cos\pars{2x} \over \expo{x} - 1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] &\
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over \expo{x} - 1}\,\dd x} & \ds{=} &
\ds{{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x\expo{-x} \over 1 - \expo{-x}}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 2}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}x\expo{-\pars{n + 1}x}\dd x}
\\ & \ds{=} &
\ds{{1 \over 2}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + 1}^{\, 2}} =
{1 \over 2}\,{\pi^{2} \over 6} = \bbx{\pi^{2} \over 12}}
\\[1cm]
\ds{{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x\cos\pars{2x} \over \expo{x} - 1}\,\dd x} & \ds{=} & 
\ds{\left.{1 \over 2}\,\totald{}{a}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{ax} \over \expo{x} - 1}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ a\ =\ 2}}
\\[2mm] & \ds{=} &
\ds{{1 \over 2}\,\totald{}{a}\bracks{\pi a\coth\pars{\pi a} - 1 \over 2a}_{\ a\ =\ 2}}
\\[2mm] & \ds{=} &
\ds{{1 \over 2}\,\totald{}{a}\bracks{{1 \over 2a^{2}} - {\pi^{2} \over 2}\,\mrm{csch}^{2}\pars{\pi a}}_{\ a\ =\ 2}}
\\[2mm] & \ds{=} &
\bbx{\ds{{1 \over 16} - {\pi^{2} \over 4}\,\mrm{csch}^{2}\pars{2\pi}}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
Then,
$$
\bbx{\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x\cos^{2}\pars{x} \over \expo{x} - 1}\,\dd x}} =
{\pi^{2} \over 12} + {1 \over 16} - {\pi^{2} \over 4}\,\mrm{csch}^{2}\pars{2\pi}} \approx 0.8849
$$

---

> The integral
>   $\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{ax} \over \expo{x} - 1}\,\dd x =
> {\pi a\coth\pars{\pi a} - 1 \over 2a}}$ has already been evaluated
>   [in this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2912283/85343).

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the following expansion:
$$
\frac{1}{e^x-1}=\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}e^{-kx}.
$$
Then switch order of summation and integration, integrate, and you will end up with the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\biggl(\frac{1}{2k^2}-\frac{4}{(4+k^2)^2}+\frac{1}{2(4+k^2)}\biggr).
$$
I'm sure you can handle it.

Comment: Can  you give some hints about middle one?

Comment: set $k= 2\tan(w)$ and continue as you would

Comment: @Zacky Expand $\cosh(2t)$ ($-\pi<t<\pi$) in a Fourier series and use Parseval's formula. (This Fourier expansion will also give you the third series, but not via Parseval's formula.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Another way is to use the residue theorem. Since, for a [suitable function](http://www.supermath.info/InfiniteSeriesandtheResidueTheorem.pdf), we have $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f\left(n\right)=-\sum\left\{ \textrm{Residues of }\pi\cot\left(\pi z\right)f\left(z\right)\textrm{ at }f\left(z\right)\textrm{'s poles}\right\} $$ we get $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{2n^{2}}+\sum_{n\geq1}\left(\frac{1}{2\left(4+n^{2}\right)}-\frac{4}{\left(4+n^{2}\right)^{2}}\right)$$ $$=\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(\frac{1}{2\left(4+n^{2}\right)}-\frac{4}{\left(4+n^{2}\right)^{2}}\right).$$ Now you have just to check that $f\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{2\left(4+z^{2}\right)}-\frac{4}{\left(4+z^{2}\right)^{2}}$ is an admissible function and $$\mathrm{Res}_{z=2i}\pi\cot\left(\pi z\right)f\left(z\right)=\mathrm{Res}_{z=-2i}\pi\cot\left(\pi z\right)f\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{4}\pi^{2}\mathrm{csch}^{2}\left(2\pi\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd like to sum up everything because (as for me) the solution is here, in the answers of [mickep](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2730762) and [Marco Cantarini](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2730947/357106), but it's not rigorous for someone else.

So we have $$I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x\cos^2 x}{e^x-1}dx=\frac12\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x}{e^x-1}dx+\frac12\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x\cos{2x}}{e^x-1}dx$$

As we know $\zeta{(z)} \Gamma{(z)} =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{z-1}}{e^x-1}dx$ so
the first integral equals to $\zeta{(2)} \Gamma{(2)} =\frac{\pi^2}6$ and the first summand is $\frac{\pi^2}{12}$.

The second summand could be expressed in the following way $$\frac12\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x\cos{2x}}{e^x-1}dx=\frac12\int_0^{\infty}\left(x\cos{2x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-nx}\right) dx=$$
$$=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-nx}x\cos{2x}dx$$
To find the latest integral one can use Laplace transform of function $x\cos{2x}$. According to the [table of Laplace transforms](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf) $$\mathfrak{L}\{ x \cos{2x}\}(s)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}x\cos{2x}dx=\frac{s^2-4}{(s^2+4)^2}$$ The integral in the middle is required integral when $s=n$.

Thus the second summand becomes $$\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2-4}{(n^2+4)^2}=\frac12\left(\frac12\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{n^2-4}{(n^2+4)^2}+\frac18\right)=$$ $$=
\frac1{16}-\frac14\left(\mathrm{Res}_{z=2i}\left(\pi\cot\left(\pi z\right)\frac{z^2-4}{(z^2+4)^2}\right)+\mathrm{Res}_{z=-2i}\left(\pi\cot\left(\pi z\right)\frac{z^2-4}{(z^2+4)^2}\right)\right)=$$ $$=\frac1{16}-\frac{1}{4}\pi^{2}\mathrm{csch}^{2}\left(2\pi\right)$$

And finally we have $I=\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac1{16}-\frac{1}{4}\pi^{2}\mathrm{csch}^{2}\left(2\pi\right)$.

Comment: I'd say it was rigorous, but perhaps not complete.