# Prove $\frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^1 \frac{\sin{ax}}{e^x-1}dx=\frac{1}{2a^2}(1+a\pi\frac{e^{a\pi}+e^{-a\pi}}{e^{a\pi}-e^{a\pi}})$

Tags: integration, summation

I found this interesting equation $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+a^2}=\frac{1}{2a^2}\left(1+a\pi\frac{e^{a\pi}+e^{a\pi}}{e^{a\pi}-e^{a\pi}}\right)$$
at [twitter](https://twitter.com/mathelegant/status/1123789036173312001). And I tried to prove it as below.

$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+a^2}\\
=&\frac{1}{2ai}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n-ai}-\frac{1}{n+ai}\right)\\
=&\frac{1}{2ai}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{0}^1 e^{(n-ai)x}-e^{(n+ai)x}dx\right)\\
=&\frac{1}{2ai}\int_{0}^1 \frac{e^{-aix}-e^{aix}}{1-e^x}dx\\
=&\frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^1 \frac{\sin(ax)}{1-e^x}dx\\
\end{align}$$

Now I need to evaluate $\frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^1 \frac{\sin(ax)}{1-e^x}dx$.
According to [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20sin%28ax%29%2F%281-e%5Ex%29&lang=ja), this integration is very complicated.

Is there easier way to evaluate this integration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{a^2+n^2}=\frac{1+a\pi\coth a\pi}{2a^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208317/show-sum-n-0-infty-frac1a2n2-frac1a-pi-coth-a-pi2a2)

Comment: No. I want to evaluate this integration directory.  But it's helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Understandable. First I would suggest to recheck the bounds of the integral, I believe the upper bound should be $\infty$, then also take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2874908/515527).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a proof of the sum. Recall that Euler gave
$$\sin\pi x=\pi x\prod_{n\ge1}(1-x^2/n^2).$$
Then $$\ln\sin\pi x=\ln\pi+\ln x+\sum_{n\ge1}\ln(1-x^2/n^2).$$
Differentiating both sides, 
$$\pi \cot\pi x=\frac1x+2x\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n^2-x^2}$$
This is 
$$\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1{n^2-x^2}=\frac{\pi}{2x}\cot\pi x-\frac1{2x^2}.$$
This is your result after $x\mapsto ix$.

Comment: You have a mistake here. After differentiation you should get $\sum\dfrac{1}{n^2-x^2} $. And then the result follows by replacing $x$ with $ix$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh ah yes. Thanks for catching that

Comment: Pending +1 delivered.